# CAML query OrderBy is not working

Tags: list, caml, sharepiont

```
SPWeb _SPweb = _SPSite.OpenWeb();
SPList _SPlist = _SPweb.Lists[FL.ToString()];

SPQuery _spquery = new SPQuery();
_spquery.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>now</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date_Of_x0020__Posted' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";//"<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date_Of_x0020__Posted' Ascending='false' /></OrderBy></Query>";///CAMLquery  for oderby posted date

 SPListItemCollection FaqCollection = _SPlist.GetItems(_spquery);

if (FaqCollection != null || FaqCollection.Count <= 0)
{    
   foreach (SPListItem item in FaqCollection)
    {    
    }
}
```

Code above is retrieving the data from a list but not ordering, it was working perfectly, but it's not working any more. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is with including **Query** tag in your CAML. Just remove it.

Here is a snippet that should work:

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="Title" />
   <Value Type="Text">now</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
 <FieldRef Name="Date_Of_x0020__Posted" Ascending="False" />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: YES ITS WORKING NOW,THANX,COULD YOU TELL ME WHAT HAPPENED ?IM  NOT CLEAR ABOUT IT,IM NEW TO SHAREPOINT.

Comment: Well, basically, it's a very common mistake. You probably copied CAML from somewhere like CAML Builder or another forum. For instance, Caml Builder includes Query tag which should not be there when using server-side C# code. You only need Where and OrderBy tags. That's all there is to it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH.YES I USED u2u,BUT IM CONFUSED HOW DID IT WORK BEFORE?

Comment: Are you sure it worked?:) when query is not correct, Sharepoint returns all items from a list.

Comment: n.b. As I'm just after laboriously finding out - there are some columns SharePoint won't sort for you - such as the Note / multiline text field

Answer (score -1):

OK try this:

"now";

This should work

Comment: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>now</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Date_Of_x0020__Posted\' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";